# Why don't my Scrapy CrawlSpider rules work?

Tags: python, scrapy

I've managed to code a very simple crawler with Scrapy, with these given constraints:

- Store all link info (e.g.: anchor text, page title), hence the 2 callbacks
- Use CrawlSpider to take advantage of rules, hence no BaseSpider

It runs well, except it doesn't implement rules if I add a callback to the first request!

Here is my code: (works but not properly, with a live example)

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapySpider.items import SPage
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class TestSpider4(CrawlSpider):
    name = "spiderSO"
    allowed_domains = ["cumulodata.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.cumulodata.com"]
    extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor()

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        #3
        print('----------manual call of',response)
        self.parse_links(response)
        print('----------manual call done')
        # 1 return Request(self.start_urls[0]) # does not call parse_links(example.com)
        # 2 return Request(self.start_urls[0],callback = self.parse_links) # does not call parse_links(example.com)

    rules = (
        Rule(extractor,callback='parse_links',follow=True),
        )

    def parse_links(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        print('----------- manual parsing links of',response.url)
        links = hxs.select('//a')
        for link in links:
                title = link.select('@title')
                url = link.select('@href').extract()[0]
                meta={'title':title,}
                yield Request(url, callback = self.parse_page,meta=meta)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        print('----------- parsing page: ',response.url)
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item=SPage()
        item['url'] = str(response.request.url)
        item['title']=response.meta['title']
        item['h1']=hxs.select('//h1/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

I've tried solving this issue in 3 ways:

- 1: To return a Request with the start url - **rules are not executed**
- 2: Same as above, but with a callback to `parse_links` - Same issue
- 3: Call `parse_links` *after* scraping the start url, by implementing `parse_start_url`, function does not get called

Here are the logs:

```
----------manual call of <200 http://www.cumulodata.com>)

----------manual call done

#No '----------- manual parsing links', so `parse_links` is never called!
```

**Versions**

- Python 2.7.2
- Scrapy 0.14.4

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a scraper that works perfectly:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapySpider.items import SPage
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class TestSpider4(CrawlSpider):
    name = "spiderSO"
    allowed_domains = ["cumulodata.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.cumulodata.com/"]

    extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor()

    rules = (
        Rule(extractor,callback='parse_links',follow=True),
        )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        list(self.parse_links(response))

    def parse_links(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select('//a')
        for link in links:
            title = ''.join(link.select('./@title').extract())
            url = ''.join(link.select('./@href').extract())
            meta={'title':title,}
            cleaned_url = "%s/?1" % url if not '/' in url.partition('//')[2] else "%s?1" % url
            yield Request(cleaned_url, callback = self.parse_page, meta=meta,)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item=SPage()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['title']=response.meta['title']
        item['h1']=hxs.select('//h1/text()').extract()
        return item
```

**Changes**:

1. Implemented `parse_start_url` - Unfortunately, when you specify a callback for the first request, rules are not executed. This is inbuilt into Scrapy, and we can only manage this with a workaround. So we do a  `list(self.parse_links(response))` inside this function. Why the `list()`? Because `parse_links` is a generator, and generators are lazy. So we need to explicitly call it fully.
2. `cleaned_url = "%s/?1" % url if not '/' in url.partition('//')[2] else "%s?1" % url` - There are a couple of things going on here:

   a. We're adding '/?1' to the end of the URL - Since `parse_links` returns duplicate URLs, Scrapy filters them out. An easier way to avoid that is to pass `dont_filter=True` to Request(). However, all your pages are interlinked (back to index from pageAA, etc.) and a `dont_filter` here results in too many duplicate requests & items.

   b. `if not '/' in url.partition('//')[2]` - Again, this is because of the linking in your website. One of the internal links is to 'www.cumulodata.com' and another to 'www.cumulodata.com/'. Since we're explicitly adding a mechanism to allow duplicates, this was resulting in one extra item. Since we needed perfect, I implemented this hack.
3. `title = ''.join(link.select('./@title').extract())` - You don't want to return the node, but the data. Also: ''.join(list) is better than list[0] in case of an empty list.

Congrats on creating a test website which posed a curious problem - Duplicates are both necessary as well as unwanted!

Comment: Many Thanks Anuj for your efforts on solving this one ! I would definitvely not have solved it by myself ! I will add then a few steps  to get rid of the ?1 parameter just before saving the Item, (probably in a pipeline), and it will be perfect.  I implemented indeed the test site to duplicate what can happen in real life ;)

Comment: For me to fully understand what the problem was, the main difficulty raised by my crawlr  is that I'm throwing Requests on url that are already in Scheduler processed queue, put there by the CrawlSpider itself through the Rules, right ? So you got rid of this by using different urls for the CrawlSpider (without ?1) and for my own Request push (with the extra ?1 parameter), I'm right ?

Comment: You're correct, Scrapy does not crawl duplicate urls (for a good reason). Since we needed it to, we modified the URL. Could've used `dont_filter=True` but the test website is heavily interlinked and produced too many duplicates, so we created one extra set of URLs. You're already aware of the other two issues - 1. Rules do not execute for a start request with custom callback, 2. `parse_links` wasn't being called properly.

Comment: @arno You don't need to remove the ?1 in a pipeline, you can do it right before returning the item.

Comment: Where and how is the `Rule` in `rules` being applied in this example?

Comment: @CatShoes For some curious reason, Scrapy does not apply `rules` on the first request if you're using `parse_start_url`. It applies them to all subsequent requests. So all subsequent responses will be run through `SgmlLinkExtractor`, causing it to extract *all links* (which is the default unless you use `allow`/`deny`/`restrict_xpath`), and pass the responses to the `parse_links` callback.

Comment: Brilliant @AnujGupta! With a similar script, but encompassing an initial authenticated login parser, appending the base_url again to my start_urls list with the query string solved the issue :)