# Scrapy incoming anchor text link

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I would like to obtain the referring anchor text link.
How would I go about obtaining the incoming anchor text link from the referring URL?

Thank you for your time!

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from wallspider.items import Website


class mydomainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mydomain"
    allowed_domains = ["www.mydomain"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain/cp/133162",]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('133162', ),deny=('/ip/', 'search_sort=', 'ic=60_0', 'customer_rating', 'special_offers', ),)
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//*')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['title'] = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
            item['description'] = site.select('//meta[@name="Description"]/@content').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

**Update:** The following is my new code according to Guys suggestion:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from wallspider.items import Website
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class anchorspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "anchor"
    allowed_domains = ["mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain.com/"]

    extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor()

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('133162', ),deny=('/ip/', 'search_sort=', 'ic=60_0', 'customer_rating', 'special_offers', ),)
, callback="parse_items", follow= True),
)

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        list(self.parse_links(response))

    def parse_links(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select('//a')
        for link in links:
            anchor_text = ''.join(link.select('./text()').extract())
            title = ''.join(link.select('./@title').extract())
            url = ''.join(link.select('./@href').extract())
            meta={'title':title,}
            meta={'anchor_text':anchor_text,}
            yield Request(url, callback = self.parse_page, meta=meta,)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = Website()
        item['anchor_text']=response.meta['anchor_text']
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['title'] = response.meta['title']
        item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
        item['description'] = site.select('//meta[@name="Description"]/@content').extract()

        return item
```

I get the following error: raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)

Comment: can you please elaborate your question with examples and sample code?

Comment: are you looking for the text of the anchor or for the link itself (href)?

Comment: @Guy I would like the incoming link text =)

Comment: `<a href="http://www.google.com">Search Engine</a>` if you want `http://www.google.com` than I guess @flyer answer is sufficient, if you need `Search Engine` you'll have to follow my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is `response.meta.get('link_text')` in response object.

Comment: I just had same question, thought that answer must be useful for someone else ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that at this stage its going to be too late to get the anchor text, instead you'll have to interfere in the link scraping stage using something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12736369/41576):

```
def parse_start_url(self, response):
    list(self.parse_links(response))

def parse_links(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    links = hxs.select('//a')
    for link in links:
        anchor_text = ''.join(link.select('./text()').extract())
        meta={'anchor_text':anchor_text,}
        ...
        yield Request(url, callback = self.parse_items, meta=meta,)

def parse_items(self, response):
    item['anchor_text']=response.meta['anchor_text']
    yield items ...
```

note the use of [meta data](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) on the request

Comment: thanks for taking the to address the question.  I'm getting the following error: 'ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)'.

Comment: I think missing scheme usually talk about a URL without http:// https:// etc, my guess is that you scrape relative urls and has to concat them the initial, i.e instead of http://stachoverflow.com/questions/1234 your request have only /questions/1234, print the request URL to find out exactly

Comment: thanks for the prompt response.  You are exactly correct.  The urls are /category/1234.  Should I prepend 'http:// www.mydomain.com?'

Comment: you are awesome.  I really appreciate your time.  So with the code `yield Request('http://www.mydomain.com/'+url, callback = self.parse_page, meta=meta,)` it correctly crawls, but it is not parsing any data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43628/discussion-between-guy-and-jason-youk)

Answer (score 2):

The `Referer` field in http request header is not set automatcially by scrapy. It's up to you whether to add the `Referer` field in your http request header and only in the situation that you have set the `Referer` field in each `Request object`, then you could get it like what you does in your code.

Refering to the [Request doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/topics/request-response.html?highlight=headers#scrapy.http.Request.headers), what you should do when yielding a `Request` object is like this:

```
def parse_xxx(self, response):
    ...... # some other operations
    headers = {
        'Referer': response.url,
    }
    ...... # some other operations
    yield Request(..., headers=headers, ...)
```

If you want to add the `Referer` field even in the initial urls, you could use `start_requests` method to yield `Request` objects rather than use `start_urls` variables. Here is the [doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/topics/spiders.html?highlight=start_requests#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests)